# wrong shape with concat and append in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have two datasets
`df1` with shape `(4045, 188)`  and  `df2` with shape `(10505, 188)`

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('ptbdb_normal.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('ptbdb_abnormal.csv')
```

To concat them i use:

```
frames = [df1,df2]
df_con = pd.concat(frames)
```

or

```
data_appended =df1.append(df2)
```

However this approach returns me Dataframe with shape `(14550,309)`  
What I need is new dataset with shape `(14750,188)`

Where am I making mistake? 
I took it from pandas docs, and SO thread here ( merging two datasets with same index)

My problem is exactly the same as the one ilustrated here:

https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/10783/how-do-i-merge-two-data-frames-in-python-pandas

[image]

Comment: Please check the `column names` in both dataframes. They should be same in order to get the result you intend.

Comment: This is the answer, columns are all different

Comment: Great then. Happy you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df1.columns=df2.columns.values
data_appended =df1.append(df2)
```